# How to integrate jquery plugin in react functional component

Tags: jquery, reactjs, jquery-plugins, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am developing an app using functional React component with react hook. I integrate jquery in my app following the code:

```
    import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
    import $ from 'jquery'
    window.jquery = window.$ = $
    function App(){
    useEffect(() => {
     if($){
        $('#btn').click(e=>{
           $('#txt').hide()
        })
      }
    },[$])
    
    return (
        <button id='btn'>Click </button>
        <p id='txt'> 
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
            Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when 
            an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen 
            book. 
        </p>
    )
```

This code perfectly works for me. But I can not add any external plugin as chosen. Please give me an idea to add a jquery plugin to my app. I used create-react-app command.

Comment: In most cases, you don't need to use `jquery` with React. Rather than looking for jquery plugins, look for React component in open-source world. You will most likely find some.

Comment: For something like this you don't need to use jQuery, you should use React. For more complex stuff like using jQuery Plugins you need to use class component with componentDidMount where you put your jQuery code. I'm not that familiar with React Hooks I'm not sure if you can use them instead of componentDidMount.

Comment: Actually this is just a demo code to show how I integrate jquery in my react app. And also my team is very comfortable with jquery. So I want to use jquery in the app. And also I don't interested to use class based components.

Comment: Hi @TakiuddinAhmed, any luck finding out how to use jQuery with functional components? I'm trying to do the same thing. I'm basically trying to integrate datatables.net into my React APP. I'm able to convert App.js into a functional component but having difficulties converting my Tbl.js component into a functional component.

Answer (score 1):

@stminion001 hooks allow us to achieve this functionality. You can integrate datatables.net using this approach. To add package in dependencies: **npm install jquery datatables.net**

```
    import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

    const $ = require('jquery');
    $.DataTable = require('datatables.net');

    const CustomDataTable = (props) => {
      
      const myTable = useRef(null);

      // componentDidMount
      useEffect(() => {
        // fill columns according to your data
        $(myTable.current).DataTable({
          data: props.data,
          'columns': [
            {title: 'first col'},
            {title: 'second col'},
            {title: 'third col'},
            ....
          ]
        });
      }, []);

      useEffect(() => {
        // componentWillUnmount
        return () => {
          $(myTable.current).DataTable().destroy();
        }
      }, []);

      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <table className='display' width='100%' ref={myTable}>

          </table>
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    }

    export default CustomDataTable;
```